# I can't get Jquery UI timepicker plugin to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the Jquery UI timepicker but when I click on the text box, the timepicker is not displayed. What I want to know is have I included all of the requirements for this type of plugin and is the function for the timepicker correct?

Below is the code:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Create a Session</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyles.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.timepicker.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {
        $( "#timepicker" ).timepicker();
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="create_session.php" method="post" name="sessionform">
<p><strong>5: Time:</strong><input type="text" id=""></p>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jquery selector is looking for an element with the `id` of `timepicker`.
In your example there are no elements with that `id`
You need to set the `id` of the `input` element to `timepicker`.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="timepicker">
```

Comment: I am an idiot! I completely forgot that I deleted "timepicker" from the id. I can't remeber why I did that but it makes my question seem silly as it was an obvious reason why it wasn't working, I just didn't see it. Thank You :)

Answer (score -1):

the documentation that I see shows it accepting an empty argument array

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({});
```

Nice to know they added this, I've wanted this in the past and will be using it on a site i'm in the process of creating

Comment: Gabe makes a good point too... haha, I missed that when I was looking at your code